# Why do we disregard the remainder while finding an oblique asymptote?

Tags: limits, asymptotics, graphing-functions

I have to find the oblique asymptote for the following equation: $$y=\frac{2x^{2}-4x-1}{x-3}$$ 
I applied long division to bring it into the form of $Q + \frac{R}{D}$ leaving me with: $$y=2x+2+\frac{5}{x-3}$$ 
And to find the oblique asymptote I took the limit as $x$ approaches infinity of $y$, that left me with: $y=\infty$ however in the textbook I am studying it states that;

> As $x$ increases then $\frac{5}{x-3}$ approaches $0$ so the equation of the oblique asymptote is $y=2x+2$

Why have we disregarded $2x+2$ in taking the limit, should it not also tend to infinity?

Comment: The asymptote is the given line. That's perfectly fine.

Comment: @Wuestenfux when taking the limit to infinity shouldnt the line y=2x+2 also tend to infinity, why do we not take the limit of that line aswell when we take limits?

Comment: Have a look at the graph.

Comment: The idea is that you are effectively comparing the given function with the line $y=2x+2$. The *difference* between these functions is $5/(x-3)$; since this value approaches $0$ as $x$ increases without bound, the function likewise *approaches* that line.

Comment: When learning about limits to infinity/limits to a specified value, I always find it helpful to actually plug in very large/very close numbers and play around with the arithmetic to see what is actually going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x):= \frac{2x^{2}-4x-1}{x-3}$ and $g(x)=2x+2.$ Then:

$$|f(x)-g(x)|= \frac{5}{x-3}$$

for $x>3$.

Hence $f(x)-g(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty.$

Thus $f(x) \approx  g(x)$ for large $x$.